# Two-dimensional array from data file in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

This is my code. I'm trying to read a two-dimensional array from a data file, but I'm getting rubbish.  What's wrong?

```
void read_array(int masyvas[][m])
{
    FILE *fp;
    if ( (fp=fopen("test.dat","wb+"))==NULL)
    {
        printf ("error \n");
        system("pause");
        exit (1);
    } 
    printf("reading file\n");
    int x, y;
    for( x = 0; x < n; ++x ) 
    {
        for( y = 0; y < m; ++y ) 
        {
            fread(&masyvas[x][y], sizeof(int),1,fp );
            printf( "%d ", masyvas[x][y] );
        }
        printf( "\n" ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should describe the data file a bit better. Is it a binary file or an ASCII file? If binary, is it stored big endian or little endian? Is there a header that describes the size of the 2d array? Make sure the sizeof(int) is the same on your system as in the file. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking the `fread()` calls; that's always a mistake.

The rest of your trouble is that `"wb+"` mode does *truncate to zero length or create binary file for update*, which is probably not what you wanted.

Replace `"wb+"` with `"rb+"` (*open binary file for update (reading and writing)*) which does not truncate the file.

Since you opened the file in the function, you should also `fclose()` it in the function.  And since you never do anything with the file except read it, you don't really need the update mode, either.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently opening your file as `wb+` mode. You want to open it for reading: `rb+`. Please see the following on [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html).

For better readability and understanding, why not following an approach like such:

- Read the file line by line (using `getline`).
- Once you read a line, simply tokenize it (using `strtok`).
- Now that you have tokens for that line, you can populate the array in your application.
- Repeat step 1-3 until `EOF`.

*Note: This assumes that you are reading a text file and that it contains delimiters between each entry that you wish to populate your array with (e.g. `1 2 3 4 5\n`, may represent one line in the file where '1', '2', '3' are values to be stored and a `\n` ends the line).*

Comment: It's a binary file, opened with `"wb+"` mode.

Comment: Note that to use `getline()` etc, you need a text file, not a binary file.  Of course, any such answer is predicated on the data file being a binary file; if it is actually a text file, what you suggest is probably much better.

Answer (score 0):

You're code sample doesn't compile.

Assuming that you're trying to read a binary file containing integers in native-byte order, something like the following should do you. Instead of reading it integer, by integer, why not just slurp it in in one fell swoop?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS  5

void read_array( int buf[ROWS][COLS] )
{
  int   x   = 0 ;
  int   len = 0 ;
  int   cnt = ROWS*COLS ; // number of ints we can handle
  FILE *fp  = fopen("test.dat", "rb" ) ; // open the file for reading in binary mode

  if ( NULL == fp ) 
  {
    printf ("error \n");
    system("pause");
    exit (1);
  } 

  printf("slurping the file\n");
  len = fread(buf,sizeof(int),cnt,fp) ;
  printf( "slurped!\n") ;

  printf( "loaded %d full rows" ,  len/COLS , len%COLS > 0 ? 1 : 0 ) ;
  if ( len%COLS > 0 )
  {
    printf( "and one partial row having %d columns." , len%COLS ) ;
  }
  printf("\n" ) ;

  for ( x = 0 ; x < ROWS ; ++x )
  {
    int y ;
    printf( "row %d: " , x ) ;
    for ( y = 0 ; y < COLS ; ++y )
    {
      printf( "%d " , buf[x][y] ) ;
    }
    printf( "\n" ) ;
  }

  return ;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int buf[ROWS][COLS] ;
  memset( buf , (char)0 , sizeof(buf) ) ;
  read_array( buf ) ;
  return 0;
}
```